# Android IOException when compressing a Bitmap

Tags: android, file-io, bitmap, compression, ioexception

In my Android project I am trying to save a bitmap to the SD card at a given location.

When I run this, I get an `IOException` every time, saying permission denied. This is on creating the FileOutputStream.

This leads me to believe that I am missing permissions, but I include `READ and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. They are declared before my `uses-sdk` block and are outside the application block. I also `read/write` text to a file elsewhere in my application and that works just fine. My current code was modified to match several of the solutions I found online, but I have not been able to successfully save a `bitmap` file.

If anyone could point out my error I would be extremely thankful.

```
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_pnm_pic);
    Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
    String outPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Recruits";

    try {
          File d = new File(outPath);
          if (!d.exists())
          d.mkdirs();

          SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-kk-mm-ss");
          String currentTime = sd.format(new Date());

          File file = new File(outPath+'/'+currentTime+".jpg");             
          FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file.getPath());

          bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, fOut);

          fOut.flush();
          fOut.close();

       }
   catch(IOException ioe){
     Toast.makeText(this, "Nice try but didn't work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: does it work if you define you outPath with Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "Recruits";? I had a similar problem with getAbsolutePath(), that fixed it. Make a Log. to see the complete path in logcat.

Comment: did u run this on emulator

Comment: I changed the outPath to 
    
   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Recruits"; 
       
and tested using Logs to see that my file was using the following path
  
   W//mnt/sdcard/Recruits/2013-06-01-17-26-50.jpg(23309)
      
When I tried testing after I created the FileOutputStream the log didn't show, meaning that is where the exception was. I also tried using an alternate constructor FileOutputStream(File) and I still get the the exception. 

Sam: I am running on this on my device

Comment: I also just found out how to check exception messages and used that to determine the problem was "Permission denied" , but I read/write text files elsewhere in the program and that works just fine

Answer (score 2):

**Change This**

```
File file = new File(outPath+'/'+currentTime+".jpg");
```

**To**

```
File file = new File(d+'/'+currentTime+".jpg");
```

And Add Permission to Manifest File:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

**Edit**
Before we start saving the image to sd card ,we need to check whether the [sd card is mounted or not](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal).

Comment: I tried the alternate constructor for the File and it didn't change anything. Also my permissions are fine, they have been checked and I read/write to external storage in other parts of my application without error.

Comment: change file.getPath() to file.getAbsolutePath()